# Ignoring client request and forcing JS reponse

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to make sure the client get an ajax response in the case the javascript fails to create a correct JS request and a HTML request is send.

For instance, the client makes a request on a specific route but as HTML and the server side makes sure he sends a JS.

Can this be done in Rails in the response part of the controller such as :

```
   respond_to do |format|
      format.js # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @subject }
    end
```

Is there a way in rails to completely ignore the client HTML request and force a JS reponse instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is, instead of the entire respond_to block, you could just:

```
render :json => @subject
```

... or whatever you want to send to the client.